# Python Only select the file that's added to the directory 5 minutes ago

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to work on code which downloads a file from a website and the zip file basically directly downloads in the downloads of my system. [note: the file name is always in random number and it doesn't contains any alphabets]

Right now while I was testing the code as it used to pick the newest file from the directory but because of using --headless chromeoptions the code isn't working and rather working on the downloaded file it works on any newest zip file in the directory.

So I want to know if there is any way to work out the --headless chromeoptions and second set the time limit for the file as well. That it can only work on any zip file which was downloaded 100 secs ago.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='downloadAction']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(10)
Ad = str(Path.home()) + "\\Desktop\\BlueDart"
loc = str(Path.home()) + "\\Downloads"
p = Path(loc)
k = list(p.glob("*.zip"))
file = max(k, key=os.path.getmtime)
if file.exists() == True:
    print(file)
    driver.quit()
else:
    print("file download failed")
#File Transfered to the main folder
Ad = str(Path.home()) + "\\Desktop\\BlueDart"
bd = Path(Ad)
if bd.exists() == True:
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(file)
    zip.extractall(Ad)
    zip.close()
    os.remove(file)
else:
    os.makedirs(Ad)
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(file)
    zip.extractall(Ad)
    zip.close()
    os.remove(file)
```